# How can I prevent server scripts I run with 'rails runner' from timing out?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a couple of ruby server scripts that live in my rails app's root folder and do stuff for it. I've been using the following command to start up each of the server scripts (which need my rails environment):

```
bundle exec rails runner 'myserverscript.rb'
```

Everything works great for a little bit, but the problem is that at some point after a several hours, my server script just stops running and I have to restart it. Is there something about rails runner where it just times out? Is there a better way altogether to be running ruby server scripts that need my rails environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep your server script up and running then you should look at using either [god](http://god.rubyforge.org/) or [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/).  They will handle the case where your script dies for some unexpected reason.  I am unaware of any timeouts in rails runner, and I would expect that you are getting an unexpected exception.